# django: failing tests from django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, testing, django-authentication, django-contrib

When I run my django test I get following errors, that are outside of my test suite:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_known_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserCustomTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 160, in test_known_user
    super(RemoteUserCustomTest, self).test_known_user()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 67, in test_known_user
    self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].username, 'knownuser')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_last_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserCustomTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 87, in test_last_login
    self.assertNotEqual(default_login, response.context['user'].last_login)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_no_remote_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserCustomTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 33, in test_no_remote_user
    self.assert_(isinstance(response.context['user'], AnonymousUser))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_unknown_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserCustomTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 168, in test_unknown_user
    super(RemoteUserCustomTest, self).test_unknown_user()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 51, in test_unknown_user
    self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].username, 'newuser')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_known_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserNoCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 67, in test_known_user
    self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].username, 'knownuser')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_last_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserNoCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 87, in test_last_login
    self.assertNotEqual(default_login, response.context['user'].last_login)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_no_remote_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserNoCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 33, in test_no_remote_user
    self.assert_(isinstance(response.context['user'], AnonymousUser))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_unknown_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserNoCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 118, in test_unknown_user
    self.assert_(isinstance(response.context['user'], AnonymousUser))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_known_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 67, in test_known_user
    self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].username, 'knownuser')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_last_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 87, in test_last_login
    self.assertNotEqual(default_login, response.context['user'].last_login)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_no_remote_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 33, in test_no_remote_user
    self.assert_(isinstance(response.context['user'], AnonymousUser))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_unknown_user (django.contrib.auth.tests.remote_user.RemoteUserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py", line 51, in test_unknown_user
    self.assertEqual(response.context['user'].username, 'newuser')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

======================================================================
FAIL: test_current_site_in_context_after_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 190, in test_current_site_in_context_after_login
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

Could anyone explain me, what am I doing wrong or what I should set to get those tests pass?

Comment: It would help if you posted your code which is producing the errors.

Comment: I really have no idea what snippet I could post. This is a already a little big project and all my tests (about 90) work fine. I just have problems with those from contrib.auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce the test results you are seeing by doing the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    .... <your middleware classes> ....
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

If you have these lines, try removing them and re-running the unit test. I do not however have a solution for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. I filed [ticket #14105](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14105)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't got the 'user' key available in your context, or even no context at all...

In your settings.py do you have the following?

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",

     etc ....
)
```

Indeed, do you have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS at all? IIRC django-admin.py startproject doesn't actually include these in the default settings.py

Hope that helps

Steve

Comment: I don't have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR in my settings, but when I added above line codes it didn't help.

Comment: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR or TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS (note the 'S')

Comment: Also, which version of Django are you on?
http://osdir.com/ml/DjangoUsers/2009-05/msg00282.html implies a fix was pushed to trunk last year --> http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/10674

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 2.6.5, you need this patch: http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11821 .

Otherwise, did you import django.contrib.admin? There are certain templates that need to exist for django.contrib.auth 's **tests** (your code *shouldn't* be affected if they are not there) to work, and django.contrib.admin happens to provide them.

Comment: Where should I make the import? In tests? I do have Python 2.6.5, but I really wouldn't like to patch my django this way and would rather wait for official release I could install.

Comment: You should import it in your settings.py (add it to the list of INSTALLED_APPS ).

However, with Python 2.6.5, it will fail without the patch regardless. If you don't want to apply it, I guess you'll have to wait until the release of 1.1.2.

Comment: I have installed 1.1.2, but this didn't help. So I guess it's not the problem.